# Intercept submit event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I want to build a simple Google extensions that would stop users to submit a tweet if it contains a blacklisted word. This requires that I can intercept the click on "Tweet" that would submit it.

After inspecting the Twitter page, I currently use the following code in the content script:

```
$('button.tweet-action').click(function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
});
```

When I click "Tweet" then I get the console output but the tweet is still submitted. Interestingly, when I use only `$('button')` then it works with many buttons. For example, I cannot delete a tweet anymore. So it kind of works just not for submitting new tweets, and I cannot tell why that's the case. Here's the snippet from Twitter HTML page:

[image]

How can I intercept and stop the submission of tweets.

Update: I've tried intercepting the form submit as suggest below. Since the form doesn't have an id, I used a class selector:

```
$('.tweet-form').submit(function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
});
```

But it's not working. For a trivial test I tried `$('.tweet-form').css(...)` which successfully changed some style changes. However intercepting the submit doesn't work; I don't even see the console output. Maybe that's because there's no `type="submit"` anywhere between the form tags.

Comment: Hook to the `submit` event of the `form` element, not the click of the button

Comment: Does the form actually try to submit, though, or is there some click handler added by the site's JS?

Comment: @CertainPerformance The fact that it's `type="button"` makes me think it's the latter.

Comment: @Christian Can you clarify, so that we can be sure of what sort of solution will work? Please don't post and then immediately go AFK, it makes it much less likely for a question to be answered when clarification is required

Comment: @CertainPerformance Please see my update. Yeah, there's no `type="submit"` anywhere so I assume that there's a click handler added to the button. Does that mean that's a deadend or for me. I can intercept all other buttons using `$('button')` like for `Delete` or `Cancel` or whatnot. Maybe because there are not within a form.

Comment: @apokryfos Yeah, `$('button')` is of course too broad and I just used it for testing if the intercept fails for each buttons. With `$('button.tweet-action')` I can delete tweets and the rest. It's just that I fail to intercept the submission of a news tweet. I see the console output but the tweets still get submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to intercept the `<Form />` **submit event** to prevent the post of a new element.

You can add it directly in your `<Form />` element:

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
  Enter name: <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Or you can use a selector:

```
document.querySelector("#myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    if(!isValid){
        e.preventDefault();    //stop form from submitting
    }
});
```

Comment: And how would the OP do that?

Comment: Added two example on how to bind the event to a method both on the element and with a query selector. Thanx for pointing it out.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini Thanks, I've tried, unfortunately with no avail. I assume that's because there's no `type="submit"` anywhere and the submit is invoked by a event handler added to the button.

Comment: When you attach a submit listener to a Form element button type does not matter as the event is attached to the Form behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Intercepting the button click event works with `stopImmediatePropagation()` instead `stopPropagation()`. The problem is that this button already has an click handler attached to it, and `stopPropagation()` only affects parent even handlers. And adding a new click event handlers doesn't overwrite existing ones. `stopImmediatePropagation()` prevents other listeners of the same event from being called.

Thus, the working solutions looks like:

```
$('button.tweet-action').click(function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  return false;
});
```